# Converting a String to ASCII format and then to HEX format

Tags: java, ascii, hex

I have to convert a normal string array with the value {"STX","ETX"} into hex value and I should get {2,3} according to http://www.asciitable.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `Map<String, Char>` such as:

```
Map<String, Char> map = new HashMap<String, Char>();
map.put("STX", '\u0002');
map.put("ETX", '\u0003');
// etc
```

I don't believe there's any such map built into the Java standard libraries.

Converting the `Char` into a hex string is then a separate step. There are lots of options there, partly depending on which version of Java you're using.

Comment: so what is there in asciitable link i have shown you ? when i try to convert that ascii values to HEX i am getting different values which is no way related to wat i am seeing in that table.

Comment: @Deepak: That ASCII table just shows the names of the non-printable characters. You haven't shown *how* you're trying to do any conversion. I've shown you how you can do it with a map, but it's pretty odd to require that...

Comment: actually what i have to do is use this to send to to serial port. so i think its better to frame the message with the same hex numbers so tat it eliminates the conversion..

Comment: @Deepak: If you're trying to send things to the serial port, you should be dealing with *bytes* rather than anything else.

Comment: yes but in the documentation of my EFT terminal they say that i have to use HEX for those non-printable characters and ASCII for other messages. I have no idea what they are trying to say. but i guess this is what they are trying to do there and i am going trial and error method to get it right...

Comment: @Deepak: I'm sure they don't really mean you need to translate them into hex. I'm pretty sure you can just give the relevant bytes...

Comment: In order to solve the problem of mistaking a data byte for a control character, a simple 
mechanism will be used whereby a <DLE> will precede any data byte which happens to 
be either one of the following control characters <DLE> / <STX> / <ETX>. A true control 
character will be recognised because of the absence of a preceding <DLE>.  
NOTE: to remove the need to cater for transparency, message data may be formatted 
exclusively in ASCII.

Comment: this is what they have.. and also they have given the convertsion ascii table so i thought they want me to convert those DLE STX ETX into hex.. is it not what they are saying ?

Comment: @Deepak: Do you *have* DLE/STX/ETX bytes in your data already though? It's not saying you have to convert *text* of STX into those bytes... it's only if you're trying to transmit data which contains those characters. It's like escaping a quote with a backslash... but this time you're escaping control characters.